# Creating a standalone on-demand Apache Spark web service

Tags: python, web-services, apache-spark, service, pyspark

I am completely new to web services and I am trying to create a web service which goes like this:

The user enters some words into a webpage.
An Apache Spark job is started in the backend which uses these words as input parameters
The results of this job are to be processed and displayed back in the webpage.
I want to make this a standalone thing without using any Spark-as-a-service offerings like Bluemix, etc

Right now, I am thinking of going with something like this: a Python server in the backend accepts requests and fires off a new Spark job with the input. When the spark job completes, the Python service processes the output and sends it back to the page.

I am not sure if this is the best way to go about doing this. Also, I'm not sure how to display the progress of the Spark job in real time in the web page.

Comment: How much data do you want to process?

Answer (score 1):

The apache livy project might fit your needs.

https://livy.incubator.apache.org/

Livy enables submission of Spark using synchronous and asynchronous result via a REST interface or a RPC client library.

Hope this help!